# LCD shows random characters (MPLAB)

Tags: c, embedded, pic, mplab, lcd

I'm trying to connect my LCD screen (16x02 QAPASS) to my PIC16F1937 on MPLAB, but it displays random characters (in this case Chinese characters, question marks and slash) instead of alphanumeric. However, all PIN connections have been declared in the library and correctly connected to the PIC. I use an XC8 compiler.

Here are the connections:

VSS --> GND
VDD --> 5V
VO --> 680Ω resistance
EN --> RD1
RW --> RD6
RS --> RD0
LCD_D4 --> RD2
LCD_D5 --> RD3
LCD_D6 --> RD4
LCD_D7 --> RD5
Anode --> 5V
Cathode --> GND

The global project is a sensor that detects the distance of an object and displays this same distance on the LCD. The fact that the LCD does not display the character compromises the rest of the project because I cannot set up the mathematical calculations if the LCD fails.

1) Library Code : lcd.h (Header Files) This is the code provided by Microchip for the LCD library and I added the PIN-LCD connections:

```
// single bit for selecting command register or data register 
#define instr 0 #define data 1

// These #defines create the pin connections to the LCD in case they 
are changed on a future demo board
#define LCD_PORT     PORTD
#define LCD_PWR      PORTDbits.RD7   // LCD power pin
#define LCD_EN       PORTDbits.RD1   // LCD enable
#define LCD_RW       PORTDbits.RD6   // LCD read/write line
#define LCD_RS       PORTDbits.RD0   
#define LCD_D4       PORTDbits.RD2
#define LCD_D5       PORTDbits.RD3
#define LCD_D6       PORTDbits.RD4
#define LCD_D7       PORTDbits.RD5

// LCD register select line

#define NB_LINES    2   // Number of display lines
#define NB_COL      16  // Number of 
characters per line
```

2) Library Code 2 : lcd.c (Source Files) Contains the commands related to the LCD

3) Main Code : main.c (Source Files)

```
#include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"
#include "lcd.h"
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

 void main(void)
 {
 // initialize the device
 SYSTEM_Initialize();

 // initialize LCD
 LCD_Initialize();

LCDGoto(4, 1);           // go to column 4, row 1
LCDPutChar("test1");
LCDGoto(3, 2);           // go to column 3, row 2
LCDPutStr("test2");

while (1)
{

}
}
```

Comment: Is `LCD_Initialize()` a library function, or one you define in your code?   (Same question for  `SYSTEM_Initialize()`)  At what point in your code do you see the _random_ characters on the LCD?  Are there return values you should be checking on the two function I asked about?  If so, I would start by looking at those values.

Comment: Why are you using a different function with `LCDPutChar("test1");` as with `LCDPutStr("test2");` when they both are passed a string? Wasn't there a compiler warning about `LCDPutChar`? It is possible that the *address* passed to `LCDPutChar()` is considered as some kind of configuration, instead of the printable character that is expected.

Comment: @ryyker `LCD_Initialize()` is a library function and `SYSTEM_Initialize ()` is a default function automatically generated by MPLAB
`LCD_Initialize()` refers to the function `void LCD_Initialize()` located in the lcd.c file. 
I see random characters once I have written the code in main.c, otherwise nothing is displayed on LCD.

Comment: @WeatherVane it's an inattention on my part to have published the code using both functions. But initially the code was compiled with only `LCDPutStr` function, for a similar result.

Answer (score 0):

@AfricaOMM,

It would appear that your code may be based on code from this [link](http://www.studentcompanion.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/LCD_Library.zip).

Because you posted only fragments it is impossible to determine just how bad the code you are trying to work from is.

The code at link I found has a Microchip copyright but it is of poor quality with bugs that will cause you several problems.

You would benefit in the long run by sorting out this mess on your own.

My best advise is to put LEDs on the signal lines that connect to your LCD module and verify that your PIC16F1937 sets each line to the correct state when the initialization code runs.

I suspect you have errors in wiring along with errors in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

The problem was related to the library.
The library that Microchip provides is full of malfunctions, so when executing commands, the PIC do not receive the supposed informations it should receive, that's why the LCD shows random characters.

I suggest you use the [library developed by electrosome](https://electrosome.com/lcd-pic-mplab-xc8/) : I confirm that it is 100% operational, thanks to them!

Another thing: to solve the contrast problem, it will ideally be necessary to connect the VO port of the LCD to a potentiometer.

Answer (score 0):

When we send a msg on LCD it shows funny characters or some weird symbols because the hardware requires some time to get refreshed. You can try to give some sleep time.after this line

```
LCDPutStr("test2").   Put above sleep time
LCD.sleep(5)
```

It worked in my case.   It worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

When we send a msg on LCD it shows funny characters or some weird symbols because the hardware requires some time to get refreshed. You can try to give some sleep time.after this line

```
LCDPutStr("test2").   Put above sleep time
LCD.sleep(5)
```

It worked in my case.